# Custom Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to have an API endpoint which delivers me customised data. Every time a QR code is scanned (can also be the same QR code several times) a new basket data set is created.

My goal is to have an API endpoint which I can query to get a JSON response with the QR-Codes, the picker who is tagged to it and the number of times that specific QR code has been scanned.

I know how to do that using normal views. However, I would prefer to use the rest-framework api.

I have read through the rest-framwork's documentation (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields) but feel a bit lost.

I have the following models:

```py
class Picker(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Pickers'

    # First name of picker
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    # Last name of picker
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

```py
class QRCode(models.Model):
    # Code
    code = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.code}'
```

```py
class Basket(models.Model):
    # DateTimestamp
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # QR-Code scanned
    qr_code = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    # Picker from who the basket comes
    picker = models.ForeignKey(Picker, related_name='picker', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.timestamp} - {self.qr_code}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serialize your Basket model and serialize it's foreign key too, you could create 2 serializers, 1 for the Basket model and one for the picker Model and in your Basket serializer, you access the picker of the basket with a serializer method field and return it serialized.

```
class PickerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
          model = Picker
          fields = '__all__'

class BasketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     picker = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

     class Meta:
          model = Basket
          fields = '__all__'

     def get_picker(self, obj):
         return PickerSerializer(obj.picker).data
```

Have a look at [serializer fields](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

Comment: Hey Woops, that's not what I was after. I found a way to get what i need using serializers.SerializerMethodField() fields. I also had to add some more fields to my models to get some additional relationships. I'll post my solution once I have some time to continue working on it. Thanks for your help!